# My ternary operarion with data from an arrray of objects in React is not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the class of an graphic bar when 'complete' is true or false. Look:

```
let data = [
    {
      name: 'Montagem de placas', dados_em_porcentagem: 100, complete: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Montagem de produtos', dados_em_porcentagem: 60, complete: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Teste de produtos', dados_em_porcentagem: 100, complete: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Embalagem de produtos', dados_em_porcentagem: 0, complete: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Montagem de Kits', dados_em_porcentagem: 0, complete: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Montagem de cabos', dados_em_porcentagem: 100, complete: true,
    },
  ];
```

```
<Bar dataKey="dados_em_porcentagem" barSize={40} className={data.complete ? "green" : "yellow"} />
```

The bars are all yellow!
The bars are all yellow!

Comment: Are you iterating over the data array? You can't use the dot notation for an array

Comment: i am not iterating. Could you write code? Im new in react

Answer (score 0):

Since data in an array, you can iterate over it and render each value like the following

```
{data.map((element) => (<Bar dataKey="dados_em_porcentagem" barSize={40} className={element.complete ? "green" : "yellow"} />))}
```

Comment: Its not working because 'Bar' is a component from a lib and only this <Bar /> is generating all bars at browser